# Problem using Nunjucks functionalities in "index.html"

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

I'm trying to use Nunjucks (client-side) as the templating component of my project. I'm using xampp, apache for the server.

The problem is that when i put "nunjucks code" inside the index.html, it doesn't compile it. If i put *"{% include "sidebar.html" %}"* it just renders that in the DOM.

I'm being able to use the render method AFTER the DOM is loaded, and in my templates, everything works.

*index.html (DOESN'T WORK):*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
      ...
     <body>
        ...
        {% include "sidebar.html" %} // This gets rendered literally
        ...
     </body>
     ...
```

So, basically i want to know if it's possible to use nunjucks functionalities in the first page that is served by apache (in this case, index.html).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
// index.html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script src = "/js/vendors/nunjucks.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    nunjucks.render('index.njk', {some-data}, (err, html) => body.innerHTML = err && err.message || html);
  });
  </script>
  <body>
  <!-- Empty body -->
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// index.njk
{% include "sidebar.njk" %}
...
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work this way. Thanks a lot for your answer anyway.

Also, there's a little detail. _body_ is not defined in that context. Maybe you meant _document.body_.

Comment: Yeah, I mean `document.body` :) Or I should write `<body id = "body">` to define `body`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky workaround, where i "add another layer of htmls".

So, in *index.html*, i have this code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  nunjucks.configure('./includes', { autoescape: true });
    nunjucks.render('dashboard_main.html', {}, function(err, res) {
      $("#main_content").html(res)
    });
  });
```

And then, dashboard_main.html can have nunjucks code.